# z3: obtain decision variables of a model

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Take the following as an example:

```
from z3 import *

a, b, c, d, e = Bools('a b c d e')
s = Solver()
s.add(Implies(a, b))
s.add(Implies(c, d))
s.add(a)
print s.check()
print s.model()
```

z3 returns:

```
sat
[a = True, b = True, c = False, d = False]
```

which is a model saying that c and d are false. But actually these two variable can be either true or false. It seems that z3 returns a model that assign `False` to decision variables (i.e. the variables whose values does not matter) by default. Is there any way to get these decision variables? In this example, it is `[c, d, e]`.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/python/z3/z3.py#L6669-L6695

Comment: Thanks for reply! This method  ```consequences(self, assumptions, variables)``` can do what i want. But when i was doing some test, i found the efficiency of this method is not good enough. I made only 1 assumptions and check about 1500 variables, and this method took about 6 seconds to finish( i used z3 in a project which should response in 2 seconds).I wonder is there any other ways or method to solver my problem with higher performance?